# C++ Windows API изменить Background окна

Tags: c++, winapi

```
case WM_ERASEBKGND: {
  HPEN pen;
  HBRUSH    brush;
  RECT rect;

  pen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, this->background);
  brush = CreateSolidBrush(this->background);
  SelectObject((HDC)wParam, pen);
  SelectObject((HDC)wParam, brush);

  GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);

  Rectangle((HDC)wParam, rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom);
  break;
}    

case WM_PAINT: {
  hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
  // TODO: Add any drawing code here...
  EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
  break;
}
```

и

```
bool Window::SetBackground(COLORREF background) {
  this->background = background;
  InvalidateRect(this->hwnd, NULL, TRUE);
  return true;
}
```

Почему вызов метода (после создания окна) не изменяет Background окна?

Comment: Ресурсы утекают, но вообще-то должно рисовать нормально. Вы уверены, что `SetBackground` вызывается? и что потом поток попадает в обработчик `WM_ERASEBKGND`?

Comment: @VTT где утекают?

Comment: Как где?  `pen` и `brush` необходимо удалять, предварительно делая в контексте активными те объекты, которые были в нем до выбора этих `pen` и `brush`

Comment: @VTT а, понял, я создаю обьект окна, вызывается SetBackground и дальше идет message loop

Comment: @VTT я не знаю как проверить попадание в поток, вроде все в одном потоке работает

Comment: брейкпоинт в дебаггере поставить и поглядеть